# Как настроить интерпретатор Python в PyCharm для работы по SSH?

Tags: python, pycharm

На виндовой машине установлен PyCharm. Есть сетевая связанность с удаленной (Ubuntu20). Настраиваю удаленный интерпретатор, но при исполнении интерпретатор берется из виртуального окружения, а не системный. Путь Location нельзя изменить - ругается на ограничение доступа, а я не хочу заливать на машину что-то отличное от питоновских скриптов. Каким образом провести настройку чтобы не учитывалось виртуальное окружение ? Есть ли возможность отключить его совсем, ну не нравится мне переливы библиотек на удаленную машину...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: PyCharm Community или Pro? В Community вообще не вижу возможности удаленного подключения.

Comment: Дали на время ноут с Pro 2023. Так сказать, заценить нужно конторе или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел, возможно глаз замылился. Нужно при создании интерпретатора выбрать не Виртуальное окружение, а Системный интерпретатор ну и в нем указать соответствующий путь к python[image: введите сюда описание изображения]